# How to move to a new screen activity after selecting a certain widget in an android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an app that takes in user's answers sums them and produces a score. Each screen is a question. How do I allow for a new screen activity to show after each question is answered? For example, one screen would be one question, then when that question is answered, the next screen is a new question, etc. How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

**INTENTS and CHANGING ACTIVITIES**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html -- Please see the first paragraph of this page.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

**Explanation**

If I understand your question correctly you are attempting to change activities through an action on your app. This is typically done using 
Intents. I highly recommend you review the data on Intents however below
you can find a very brief example of changing intents based on a button click.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
Button btnContinue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    btnContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCrows);
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

While this is not a very "complete" or in-depth example it is more than enough to get you started. As you can see we are using the startActivity() method to actually run the intent where we reference both the activity we are on as well as where we would like to go. The API docs referenced in this post also explain this very well.